# toggle effect in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, why is this not working:

```
$("#togglePanel").click(function(e){        
    $("#toolpanel").toggle(function(){
        $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: 0, width: "100%"}, 500);
    }, function(){
        $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: "341px", width: "576px"}, 500);
    });
});
```

But when I do this, it works:

```
$("#togglePanel").click(function(e){        
    $("#toolpanel").toggle(function(){
        $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: 0, width: "100%"}, 500);
    });
});
```

Thanks...

Comment: This is a little unusual, so let's clarify something. Is your intent that the user must first click `#togglePanel` (which has no apparent effect) but then after that click the user will be able to click `#toolpanel` to toggle between the two animations?

Comment: You should not be using both the click and toggle events together. Toggle internally generates a click event on the object. If #toolpanel is inside #togglePanel you may be running into event collisions.

Do you need the wrapping click event?

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: No. But the 'togglePanel' is actually a button that the user can click to show/hide 'toolpanel'.

Comment: When the user clicks 'togglePanel' button, the 'toolpanel' div should hide/show. That's all I want to achieve. How can I do that, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function "uses the click event internally".  That is to say, it binds functions to click events, so you don't need to call `click` as well.  Try this:

```
$("#togglePanel").toggle(function(){
    $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: 0, width: "100%"}, 500);
}, function(){
    $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: "341px", width: "576px"}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Note that `#togglePanel` and `#toolpanel` are two separate elements. So this is not quite equivalent. This should still be based on `#toolpanel` but have an **additional** toggle for `#togglePanel` to show/hide `#toolpanel` based on Shaoz's last comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the `#togglePanel` is showing and hiding the `#toolPanel`, I would separate their two events rather than nest them. So, do something like this...

```
$("#togglePanel").toggle(function(e){        
    $("#toolPanel").show();
}, function() {
    $("#toolPanel").hide();
});

$("#toolpanel").toggle(function(){
    $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: 0, width: "100%"}, 500);
}, function(){
    $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: "341px", width: "576px"}, 500);
});
```

You don't need to have them nested to achieve the effect you want.

Additionally, the one problem that may arise with my solution is that the #toolPanel's "toggle" state is saved even between hiding and showing it. So, you may want to reset its toggle status when you hide it (do that in the `#togglePanel.toggle()`).

Comment: @Shaoz - No problem. I hope that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem by mixing up all your answers and come up with this:

```
$("#togglePanel").toggle(function(e){        
    $("#toolpanel").hide();
    $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: 0, width: "100%"}, 500);
}, function() {
    $("#toolpanel").show();
    $("#orderMap").animate({marginLeft: "341px", width: "576px"}, 500);
});
```

It works as I expected. All I had to do was to add the hide and show methods to the 'toolpanel' div.

But thanks for your help though. It was your answers that gave me the headstart to my solution.